# DNS/DHCP configuration in /config/config.boot vs. /etc/dnsmasq.d

Tags: dnsmasq, ubiquiti, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have an Edgerouter 4 and I am trying to make sense of the configuration areas for DHCP and DNS, when `use-dnsmasq enable` is set.

I see four places where the configuration can be done:

1. from the command line (`set service dns forwarding ...` [seems to be the way](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010913367-EdgeRouter-DNS-Forwarding-Setup-Options) to provide DNS parameters (but not DHCP?))
2. by editing (EDIT: a copy of) `/config/config.boot` and loading it up

These two seem to be tightly linked together, the command line config seems to be written to `/config/config.boot`

3. by configuring `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
4. by adding a file to `/etc/dnsmasq.d`

The configurations follows the [`dnsmasq` configuration file](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), I have the file `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-dhcp-config.conf` which was created for me.

Note: I have a strong preference for the approach where `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` would be all commented out as it is today, and have all my DNS and DHCP cpnfiguration in files living in `/etc/dnsmasq.d`. I can accept that this configuration will not be visible from the GUI (in the `DNS` page).

#### My questions

- How do these configuration approaches work together?
- Is it possible to only use the approach 3. or 4.?
- If yes:

  - are there drawbacks? (= inconveniences such as the need to backup teh files during an upgrade, lack of visibility in the GUI, etc.)
  - are there incompatibilities? (= something can be configured exclusively via 1., 2. or 3./4.?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) generally you would never do, as a reboot would be required to apply config changes. The `set` commands which ultimately save their changes there should be used instead, outside of specific circumstances like scripting config generation en masse when deploying a lot of systems with similar configs.

3) isn't viable because anything that reconfigures dnsmasq will overwrite changes.

4) will work, but won't survive a firmware upgrade so is inadvisable.

The `set` commands are preferred. Depending on what you're looking to configure exactly, the `dns forwarding` custom config may suffice even though it doesn't go into the DHCP portion of the dnsmasq config.

Comment: Thank you, I have a few questions about your answer: in 2) I realized I forgot to add "a copy of" - updated in the question. As for 4): would keeping the file in /config/ and have a link help? Also, `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-dhcp-config.conf` is generated at some point and holds a part of the `dnsmasq` configuration (while another piece is in `/config/config.boot` so the whole thing looks quite messy as it stands.